# PHP Class inheritance and data validation

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm having some issues on how to design my two classes so that I avoid "copying" and "pasting" code in order to maximize re-usability. I have a class that creates users. In essence, it validates entries and then inserts users in the database. On the other hand, I have another class that updates the user, but only some portion of the user's profile. Here's my first class.

```
<?php
class newEmployee extends CoreConnect {

    protected $_info = array();
    protected $_errors = array();

    public function __construct($data) {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_info = array(
            'firstname' => '',
            'lastname'  => '',
            'street'    => '',
            'postal-code'   => '',
            'province'      => '',
            'email'         => '',
            'country'       => '',
            'userUpdate'     => '',
            'wage'          => 0,
            'emp-status'    => '');

            $this->_info = $data + $this->_info;
    }


    protected function validate() {

        if($this->_info['firstname']=="" || $this->_info['lastname']==""){
            $this->_errors[] = "Employee's full name is required";
        }

        if(ctype_alpha ( $this->_info['firstname'].$this->_info['lastname'])==false) {
            $this->_errors[] = "Employee name is invalid";
        }

        if($this->_info['wage']!="") {
            if(!is_numeric($this->_info['wage'])) {
                $this->_errors[] = "Salary invalid";    
            }
        }

        if($this->_info['userUpdate']=="" && isset($this->_info['userUpdate'])) {
            $this->_errors[] = "User missing";
        }       

        if($this->_info['email']!="") {
            if (!filter_var($this->_info['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $this->_errors[] = "Email address is invalid";
            }
        }



    }   

    public function errors() {
        return $this->_errors;  
    }

    public function add(){
        $this->validate();
        if(empty($this->_errors)) {
            $params = array();
            $query = $this->_INSTANCE->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO employees 
            (ID, firstname, lastname, email,  street, postal_code, province, country, employee_type, member_since) 

            VALUES (NULL, :firstname, :lastname, :email,  :street, :postal_code, :province, :country, :status, NOW())
                        ");
            $params[":firstname"]   = $this->_info["firstname"];
            $params[":lastname"]    = $this->_info["lastname"];
            $params[":street"]      = $this->_info["street"];
            $params[":email"]       = $this->_info["email"];
            $params[":postal_code"] = $this->_info["postal-code"];
            $params[":province"]    = $this->_info["province"];
            $params[":country"]     = $this->_info["country"];
            $params[":status"]      = $this->_info["emp-status"];

            return $query->execute($params);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the `validate` methods validates which ever entries I wish to validate. The class that updates users' data looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'class.newEmployee.php';
class updateEmployee extends newEmployee {

    public function __construct($data) {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_info = array(
            'employeeID'    => "",
            'firstname' => '',
            'lastname'  => '',
            'email'     => '',
            'street'    => '',
            'postal-code'   => '',
            'province'      => '',
            'country'   => '');

            $this->_info = $data + $this->_info;
    }

    public function update(){
        $this->validate();


        if(empty($this->_errors)) {
            $params = array();
            $query = $this->_INSTANCE->pdo->prepare("UPDATE employees 
            SET 
                firstname=:firstname, 
                lastname=:lastname, 
                street = :street,
                postal_code = :postal_code,
                province = :province,
                email = :email,
                country  = :country
            WHERE ID = :ID ");

            $params[":ID"] = $this->_info["employeeID"];
            $params[":firstname"] = $this->_info["firstname"];
            $params[":lastname"] = $this->_info["lastname"];
            $params[":street"] = $this->_info["street"];
            $params[":postal_code"] = $this->_info["postal-code"];
            $params[":province"] = $this->_info["province"];
                $params[":email"] = $this->_info["email"];
            $params[":country"] = $this->_info["country"];


            return $query->execute($params);

        } else {
            return false;
        }   
    }
}
```

In this case I want to validate not only what the `validate` method validates from `newEmployee` but also a new input called `employeeID`. Basically what I want to achieve is to be able to somehow use portions of the parent class to the child class and also bringing in new validations. It's obviously inconvenient to override the `validate` method just to add another validation point. It makes sense to carry the same validation used in creating a new employee and also updating the employee. Code re-usability is a must in this case since it must be uniform whether creating an employee or updating his/her profile.

Any suggestions or references would be great...

Comment: This question belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this class for validations, the function "validar" recieve two parameters, the firts is the data to validate and the second are the rules.

```
  <?php 
/**
* Esta clase valida todos los datos de entrada al servidor
*/
class Validador 
{

    public $errores = array();      


    /**
     * esta funcion valida las variables que vengan en el post y el get
     * dependiendo de las reglas recibidas
     */
    public function validar($datos, $reglas){

        $valido = TRUE;

        foreach ($reglas as $campo => $regla) {

            $verificadores = explode('|', $regla);

            foreach ($verificadores as $verificador) {
                $valor = isset($datos[$campo]) ? $datos[$campo] : NULL;
                if( !$this->$verificador($valor, $campo) ){
                    $valido = FALSE;
                }
            }

        }
        return $valido; 
    }

    /**
     * valida que un valor sea un email valido
     */
    private function email($valor, $campo){
        $valido = filter_var($valor, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if(!$valido){
            $this->errores[] = "El campo ".$campo." necesita un email valido";              
        }
        return $valido;
    }

    /**
     * verifica que un valor no este vacio
     */
    private function requerido($valor, $campo){
        $valido = !empty($valor);
        if(!$valido){
            $this->errores[] = "El campo ".$campo." es requerido";              
        }
        return $valido;
    }

    /**
     * comprueba que un rut sea valido
     */
    private function rut($valor, $campo){
        //return TRUE;
        $dv = substr($valor, -1);
        $rut = substr($valor, 1,-3);

        $s=1;
        for($m=0;$valor!=0;$valor/=10)
            $s=($s+$valor%10*(9-$m++%6))%11;

        $valido = chr($s?$s+47:75) == $dv;
        if(!$valido){
            $this->errores[] = "El campo ".$campo." necesita un rut valido";                
        }
        return $valido;
    }

    /**
     * verifica que el token recibido sea igual al de la sesion activa
     */
    private function token($valor, $campo){
        $valido = $valor == $_SESSION['token'];
        if(!$valido){
            $this->errores[] = "El campo ".$campo." necesita un token valido";              
        }
        return $valido;
    }

    /**
     * verifica si el valor recibido es numerico
     */
    private function numero($valor, $campo){
        $valido = is_numeric($valor);
        if(!$valido){
            $this->errores[] = "El campo ".$campo." necesita un numero valido";             
        }
        return $valido;
    }

    /**
     * verifica si el valor recibido es texto
     */
    private function texto($valor, $campo){
        $valido = is_string($valor);
        if(!$valido){
            $this->errores[] = "El campo ".$campo." necesita un texto valido";              
        }
        return $valido;
    }

    /** 
    *   verifica si el valor recibido es un array
    **/
    private function arreglo($valor, $campo){
        $valido = is_array($valor);
        if(!$valido){
            $this->errores[] = "El campo ".$campo." necesita un arreglo valido";                
        }
        return $valido;
    }

    /** 
    *   verifica si el valor recibido es un array
    **/
    private function fecha($valor, $campo){
        $pattern = '/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/'; // regex para fecha formato: DD-MM-AAAA ej: 17-07-2014

        $valido = preg_match($pattern, $valor);
        if(!$valido){
            $this->errores[] = "El campo ".$campo." necesita una fecha valida ej: 14-04-2014";              
        }
        return $valido;
    }
}
```

?>

and i called this way:

```
 $reglas = array(
                'nombre' => 'requerido',
                'descripcion' => 'requerido',
                'token' => 'token|requerido'
                );
 $validador = new Validador();
 if ($validador->validar($_POST, $reglas)) {                        
    //valid data                        
 }else{
    // invalid data
 }
```